# Java Left Shift & Right Shift

Tags: java

This is more like a clarification question. Suppose I have a value in int myvar whose bit representation is 10000000000000000000000000000000. Now thats 32 bits the actual size of int in java (please correct me if this assumption cannot be made).

Now the question is whats the value of myvar << 1? is it 000...000 because the '1' in the MSB gets shifted out? Also what will be myvar >> 1? will it be 110000....00000?

Lastly how do we determine the number of bits taking up a variable? I mean do we have sizeOf(int) function in Java giving us 32 as the answer? Thanks

Comment: All java primitives have bit sizes that are predetermined and unchanging. Check them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). For example, an int is always 32 bits. For your question "_whats the value of ..._" You can simply run some code to see.

Comment: @Takendarkk sure but I need to problematically be able to determine its size.

Comment: I don't see why you need to do that because they are always the same. If you have an int it is 32 bits, if you have a short it is 16 bits, and so on.

Comment: As to the behavior of `<<` and `>>`, why not simply try it? As to variable sizes, there are only a few primitive types in Java, and each wrapper class has a `SIZE` constant that gives you what you want. If you want to get baroque, you could even put them into a map so you could look them up by class (e.g., `int bitSize = bitSizeMap.get(int.class);`)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to do this programmatically (Java doesn't have macros like C where you could conditionally define some type to be either an `int` or `long` in an `.h` file).  If you have a `Class` that you got via reflection, I don't think there's a method to get the size, but you can use a map as in Ted's comment since there are only a handful of primitives.  I still cannot think of a legitimate reason for doing this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Suppose I have a value in int myvar whose bit representation is 10000000000000000000000000000000.... Now the question is whats the value of myvar << 1? is it 000...000 because the '1' in the MSB gets shifted out? Also what will be myvar >> 1? will it be 110000....00000?

Let's find out

```
int myvar = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(myvar));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(myvar << 1));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(myvar >> 1));
```

Outputs

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
0
11000000000000000000000000000000
```

> do we have sizeOf(int) function in Java giving us 32 as the answer?

Not exactly. There is however the SIZE field in the wrapper types,

```
System.out.println("Integer: " + Integer.SIZE);
System.out.println("Double: " + Double.SIZE);
```

Output is

```
Integer: 32
Double: 64
```

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of bit shifting is correct. The following code will confirm that.
As for a sizeOf function in Java, all ints take up 32 bits. Period.  As for a more general sizeOf function, then that is a more complicated subject that other SO questions answer.  That said EHCache has a pretty decent implementation [here](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/pool/sizeof/SizeOf.html).

```
    int v1 = 1 << 31;
    int v2 = v1 << 1;
    int v3 = v1 >> 1;
    int v4 = v1 >>> 1;

    // -2147483648 is 10000000000000000000000000000000 and has 1 bits set
    System.out.println( v1 + " is " + Integer.toBinaryString(v1) + " and has "+Integer.bitCount(v1)+" bits set");    

    // 0 is 0 and has 0 bits set
    System.out.println( v2 + " is " + Integer.toBinaryString(v2) + " and has "+Integer.bitCount(v2)+" bits set");

    // -1073741824 is 11000000000000000000000000000000 and has 2 bits set    
    System.out.println( v3 + " is " + Integer.toBinaryString(v3) + " and has "+Integer.bitCount(v3)+" bits set");    

    // 1073741824 is 1000000000000000000000000000000 and has 1 bits set
    System.out.println( v4 + " is " + Integer.toBinaryString(v4) + " and has "+Integer.bitCount(v4)+" bits set");
```

Answer (score 0):

int are 32bits signed hence the first bit is used for sign +/- 
So actually only 31 bits decides the value.
Please refer below URL
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

also URL https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58472/bitshift-code-compacting/58498#58498

has a working code for bit shifting - both right/left bit shift are supported. you can take any one program from the question or from answer , run it with a number you want to shift and degree to which you wanted to shift...you can immediatly get an answer...